# JUnit. Parallel running. But all the test methods processing singleton instance. How to solve?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, parallel-processing, webdriver

So, I have a couple of `JUnit` classes, each one contains a list of test methods.
Each method is independent of each other, there is no direct connection.
But we have indirect connection: all methods processes one singleton object (it is `Selenium Web Driver` Instance, yes, I use 1 `Web Driver` Instance for all my tests, because for making new object instance we spend a really lot of time! ).

And It is all ok, when test methods execute step by step in one thread.  But it is too long too,

So, I decided to increase speed, 
How? -  I decided to run all the test methods in the parallel mode. For this I use maven with the special configuration for parallel test execution.

But I think, it is a source a new problem, because - in result we have parallel methods execution, but we still work just with **single** Web Driver Instance.

I'm trying to find the optimal solution:

I want that the tests will be executed in parallel mode - it is really fast.

I don't want that for every test new object is created - it is a very long process.

What advice can you provide for me?

How would you have solved this problem?

Comment: How many tests do you have?

Comment: maybe its still fast even with the cost of creating a new driver per thread (not per test)

Comment: Currently, I have 2 test classes, each one contains 5-7 test methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, webDriver is not thread-safe. Imho, best practice is to run each test class using individual webDriver instance in separate thread. The optimal number of threads is 
`int threadNum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;` The executing time of my projects reduced from 30 minutes to 4. 
Exactly the same method is used in Thucydides framework.

Answer (score 3):

There is no alternative around this. If the tests are running in parallel, you can not use a single `WebDriver` instance, you must instantiate one `WebDriver` instance per test case.

One way to get a speedup by running the tests serially is to reuse the `WebDriver` object because starting up the `WebDriver` tends to be a step which takes a long time. Another common optimisation is to reuse the `FirefoxProfile` if a `FirefoxDriver` is being used because the creation of the profile is also slow.

If you do choose to reuse the `WebDriver` object, make sure you try to clean up the instance as best as possible in `tearDown`. For example, by clearing cookies:

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the actual performance bottlenecks are in your tests, you could do something gross like tacking a `synchronized` wrapper around your driver so that you still only have one but all access to it is serialized.

You could potentially change your test to have a `ThreadLocal` reference to a driver so you have one driver per thread.

Comment: How would wrapping `synchronized` help performance? You are essentially forcing it to be serial.

Comment: It depends if the reason for the slowness is in the driver or in the surrounding test code. Yes, if the `WebDriver` is the problem, it won't help much to have one and synchronize access to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Jute maven plugin](https://github.com/raydac/jute) provides isolation of JUnit test methods(!) through their start as external JVM processes, also you can define specific JRE for tests