# Running parallel JUnit tests in same JVM process without Maven/Apache SureFire?

Tags: java, maven, ant, junit, testng

***Note: This question is NOT a duplicate of the above***

I'm looking for a plugin or some `TestRunner` that will allow me to run JUnit suites in parallel in the same JVM process, without using Maven. (I'm unfortunately not able to use Maven for this project.) And, I need to re-use connections to the server and so am using a Singleton pattern. (I can't have that many simultaneous connections to the server.)

I've pretty much scoured the whole Internet, but no solution has worked. (I'm also using JUnit `@Categories` and `@Parameterized`, so it would be great if I could get those to work too, but at this point I'm kind of desperate.) Each solution I've tried makes a new JVM process for each test or suite.

Can anyone provide a library, some sample code, or point me in the right direction as to how I could go about this? I can use `ant`, but based on [ant's description of Parallel tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html), I don't think it would work. Also, even if I have to switch to TestNG, I'll do it.

Also, I know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057314/junit-parallel-running-but-all-the-test-methods-processing-singleton-instance) question is related, but I really need to re-use those connections and use a Singleton pattern.

Any help would be appreciated, SO! Thanks.

Comment: First hit in google for "junit parallel" gives this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423627/running-junit-tests-in-parallel) and the Junit page gives [this](https://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/)

Comment: @Mark Yes, I've looked at that SO answer (see the title of the question and the second last sentence) and also junit-toolbox, which also does not give me what I want. (The SureFire plugin uses Maven, and the answer to the other SO question was to not use a Singleton pattern, which is not an option for me.)